# What makes Phenom II series different from the Athlon II series?

Tags: cpu, amd-phenom, amd-athlon

Ok thats my CPU "Athlon II X2 250"
But, What would the difference If I used an Phenom one ? Is there an difference between Athlon X2 II and Phenom X2 ? II (2 "i"'s just like F4 Phantom II)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would the difference If I used a Phenom II X2 processor

Wikipedia says it best:

> The Athlon II series is based on the AMD K10 architecture and derived
>   from the Phenom II series. However, unlike its Phenom siblings, it
>   does not contain any L3 Cache.

[Athlon II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_II)

Additionally,

> The Phenom II triples the shared L3 cache size from 2MB (in the
>   original Phenom line) to 6MB, leading to benchmark performance gains
>   as high as 30%.

[Phenom II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenom_II)

Worth pointing out there are specific Phenom II processors, which are based on a Athlon II core,  which also do not have L3 cache although still marketed as a Phenom II.

Comment: The comments I flagged had numerous typographical errors in them.  Even if I was going to answer them I didn't understand them.  They also have nothing to do with the question you asked.  Extended commentary is subject to be removed.